# In which states (USA) can someone “live easily without speaking any English”?

Tags: american-english, spanish, bilingual

Russian polyglot Dmitry Petrov said in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAWXVv0Tw_w&feature=youtu.be&t=555):

> ...испанский язык наступает английскому языку на пятки. Мы знаем, что в США есть несколько штатов, где можно свободно жить, зная испанский.

Translation for this quote (thanks for @Enguroo for the correct translation):

---

> Spanish is "snapping at the heels of English". We know that in America there are a few states where one can live easily without speaking any English.

---

Which (USA) states is Petrov referring to?

Comment: The following translation may be helpful: Spanish is "snapping at the heels of English". We know that in America there are a few states where one can live easily without speaking any English.

Comment: Many states, depending on region. Moreso in the Mexico border states, of course. But you can also do it here in New York City itself. And many 3rd generation Chinese in Chinatown - the whole neighborhood - never learn to speak English. There are dedicated media, everything. You speak Russian - you could live in Brighton Beach here and never speak a word of English in your life. And that’s only the tip of the iceberg. In New York alone there are 176 different and unique languages spoken! America is a pluralistic society.

Comment: One may spend their lifetime in one of the [ethnic enclaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_enclaves_in_North_American_cities) and avoid speaking English almost entirely. However, your employment opportunities as well as social life will be severely restricted if you don't speak good English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because determining where one can live without using English isn't really *about* the English language or its usage.

Comment: @Lawrence I’m usually close-vote happy, but I differ from you on this one. Distributional analysis is scholastic topic.

Comment: @DanBron I also wondered about this for awhile since "not-X" *is* still "about X", but that argument doesn't quite hold here - questions about 'languages other than English' are considered off-topic here. On distributional analysis - had it been about regional English dialects or *anything* related to the English language, that would have been a fair comment. However, consider other English-dominant countries such as India(?), Singapore or The Philippines, or even (at a stretch) globally: "Where can I live without needing to know English?" seems to skirt a little wide of the EL&U charter.

Comment: What do you mean by *"... video next"*?

Comment: It’s a ridiculous statement to begin with. First off, what does ‘live easily’ mean? At what point is life ‘easy’? I’ve known several people who lived in very monolingual Beijing and led quite easy lives overall despite not speaking a word of Mandarin (conversely, I’ve known many locals living in the same city and leading exceedingly hard lives). And “some states” is far too vague. You can get by with Spanish only in Spanish Harlem just fine; it’ll be much harder in Ithaca or Binghamton, though they’re also both in the state of New York.

Comment: @Janus re 'state' that's why this is a good question. The OP is skeptical of the statement and the nuance that makes the statement more accurate, namely that 'state' is simplistic, and 'neighborhoods' would be closer.

Comment: @Mitch I agree; my comment was aimed specifically at Petrov, not the question here. I do feel like this isn’t the best Stack for the question, though; [skeptics.se] would probably be a better fit, since it’s basically a question doubting the objective veracity of a claim (about English).

Comment: Up until maybe 1960 there were probably 100-200 people living in rural/small town Minnesota who spoke primarily Norwegian.  Some knew very little English.  I don't doubt that there were similar enclaves in other locales for Polish, German, Chinese, etc, even in big cities such as New York.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This works best if we consider Puerto Rico a state. :) Even New Mexico, the only legally bilingual state, is filled with people who don't speak Spanish. But not Puerto Rico.

Comment: @tchrist Hawaii is legally bilingual ([English and Hawaiian are both official languages](https://www.capitol.hawaii.gov/hrscurrent/Vol01_Ch0001-0042F/05-Const/CONST_0015-0004.htm)).

Comment: California, Colorado, Illinois, Massachusetts, New Mexico, Oregon, and Vermont. – [List of Sanctuary Cities](http://www.apsanlaw.com/law-246.List-of-Sanctuary-cities.html) indemnified by their State from Federal recourse. I live in a red state that votes blue; if you leave the city proper, don't expect it to go so well (you need to look at *cities*, not entire states, and then specific neighborhoods within them).

Comment: @Mazura: You seem to be confused. Speaking English is *not* a requirement for legal immigration, only for naturalization; and even there there are exceptions to the requirement. So "sanctuary cities" are not relevant to the question of where you can live without speaking English.

Comment: I'm surprised that this was closed as opinion based. Native language has been well studied in the US. So where there are communities that primarily speak a particular language is well know. It's only opinion to you if you don't know.

Comment: @Mitch, yeah, me too surprised... :(

Comment: @misdeed you can vote to reopen

Comment: @Mitch I can't.

Comment: @1006a Hawaii may be legally bilingual, but [the proportion of people who speak any Hawaiian is pretty small and those who only speak Hawaiian negligeable](https://www.ethnologue.com/19/language/haw/).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet at my age, and **if I didn't speak English but only Italian** were I to emigrate to a different country, I'd totally avoid the Asian continent. It can't be easy to communicate with local residents or learn  the script.  If left with no choice, I would desperately search for an Italian community, so as not to feel isolated.  So Petrov's assertion is not such a ridiculous statement. It is *easier*  to live in a country that speaks a similar language to your own, even easier if you find entire neighbourhoods that speak the same language. Don't you think so?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Of course it is easier to live somewhere where you speak the local language, but it’s also possible to live quite easily without it, depending on many other factors. And as you say, you’d look for Italian _communities_; talking about _states_ in this way doesn’t make any sense. Neighbourhoods, areas—definitely. Cities even, perhaps. Entire states? Far too wide a net for the statement to be of any actual use.

Comment: @Mitch Oh, indeed. The law I linked to even says that not everything has to be in Hawaiian, official status notwithstanding. I don't think there is anywhere in the US where it's genuinely *easy* to not speak English, in the sense that all doors are open to you and there's little risk of dire consequences from the lack of English, unless you happen to be independently wealthy and can afford to hire trustworthy interpreters and such. Of course ymmv on what constitutes "easy", which is why I voted to close this question as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet but you would also agree that it is easier for an English speaking person to live practically anywhere in the world. More so than someone whose only language is Italian, Czech or Hungarian (although these countries tend to study English as a second language at schools). And if 48% of the population in N. Mexico and 39% in Texas already speak Spanish, well, practically that is the size or population of a country.

Comment: @misdeed You need to clearly specify what counts as "liv[ing] easily" and what your threshold is for "no need" to speak English (I doubt you really mean zero need ever). Otherwise, you're at the whim of what various people think is "easy enough" living. You probably also should specify what kind of evidence you consider acceptable and sufficient, since this is really more of a sociological question than English-language, so the kinds of sources that are usually offered at ELU (dictionary definitions, corpus searches, etc.) won't work. Frankly, I think you'd get much better answers at Skeptics.

Comment: @1006a I think it is pretty easy to see that 'easy to live' means, in contrast to living in a family with bilinguals who can help you, rather in an area where the daily activities of life outside the home can be conducted in the non-standard language: getting groceries, post office, shops. Maybe even doctors and lawyers (which is the case for lots of areas in the Southwest and in southern Florida (also big cities up north).

Comment: @Mitch That isn't clear to me at all. The title says "*no need to speak English*" and I don't believe there's any state in the Union where that's the case. Maybe it *should* be, but I don't think we're there yet.

Comment: You can rollback the edit if you *do* want to know where in the US it is not necessary to speak English. It seems to me that you were only paraphrasing Petrov's statement but some users are finickier than others :)

Comment: "it’s also possible to *live quite easily* [?] without [speaking the local language], depending on many other factors." - that's why it's on hold.

Comment: @Mazura see my comment above to 1006a where I explain what 'easy to live means', where there are enough speakers in the community, not related to you running and businesses, for you to conduct your life in that language. The answer is California, Arizona, New Mexico, Texas, southern Florida, and smaller communities in big cities further north.

Comment: @Mitch - we're in agreement (other than you left out the part about living relativity free of the worry of deportation - that's pretty high on my list of things that make life easy) but the OP needs to define what *live easily* means.

Comment: @Mazura 1) legal status is an interesting but secondary issue for language use. 2) The OP is taking a transcription of a Russian statement by someone else and then translating. So it is two maybe three steps removed from the OPs meaning. That said, it is obvious what 'live easily' means or if not, to give an interpretation that is it meaningful.

Comment: @Dan Bron If it's any help I gather that there are more than 250 languages spoken in London. Don't know how that compares to New York, but many Londoners are proud to pitch themselves as "the most cosmopolitan city on earth"

Comment: @DanBron if you haven't already, please cast your vote to reopen. It just needs one more vote.

Comment: Please reopen this question!

Comment: Yay! It's ropened!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree with @Lawrence above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary: For Spanish, southern California, Arizona, New Mexico, Texas, southern Florida, plus many urban areas further north.  There may be pockets of other languages but they are small. See [wikipedia for links to data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language_in_the_United_States).

'Easy to live' means, language-wise, that you can show up to most any business and expect that someone there will know Spanish. Groceries, banks, post office. One could be super-rich and hire a translator, or have a family member who is bilingual to do all these things, but those aren't easy to do. The idea Petrov is trying to get across is that there are so many Spanish speaking people and so much cultural acceptance of Spanish that it is not hidden in the home, like many immigrant or colonial languages are, and that there is enough concentration (not just one 'specialty' grocery store).

As to 'state', that's a bit of exaggeration. You can't go absolutely anywhere in those states and be guaranteed someone you don't know will be available to speak Spanish. But, and this is I think Petrov's point, that for large parts of those places I mentioned, you *do* have a guarantee.

In the big city areas in those places mentioned, there you'll be able to go to banks, buy property, and even conduct some legal matters. Even though the US doesn't have English as an officially mandated language of law, all records of laws are recorded in English. That said, translation services are almost always allowed in a court. Also, almost all US official forms have Spanish translations.

US has a number of immigrants populations with concentrations, but Spanish, as a seemingly non-standard language, is very widespread.

What all this means is that, as a native Spanish speaker, if you don't know any English at all, you'd be able to conduct business/daily life outside the home in Spanish with few problems.

---

There are a lot of complications to the above. Just one example: there are many 'second generation', children of those who immigrated, who may speak Spanish at home, but very often speak only English, with only hearing proficiency in Spanish.

Answer (score 11):

Hardly a neutral phrase, Petrov’s “snapping at the heels of English” ignores three important factors: (1) the history of the states bordering Mexico, which once were part of that country and thus had Spanish-speaking residents before they became US states, (2) English as language of instruction in public schools, and (3) that growth in the Hispanic demographic, which [until the Great Recession was fastest across the nation](http://www.pewhispanic.org/2016/09/08/latino-population-growth-and-dispersion-has-slowed-since-the-onset-of-the-great-recession/), does not necessarily correlate with native language, now or in the future.

For instance, incumbent Texas Sen. Ted Cruz, [by his own admission](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=k_h-6wB-EQI), speaks rather poor Spanish (his father is Cuban), while his challenger, [Rep. Beto O'Rourke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZuFhE3IdoY), who grew up in El Paso, is bilingual, though his Mexican Spanish has a moderate American accent. Cruz has a Texas accent, while O'Rourke does not. These social realities aren't easily crammed into statistics, but do suggest that the cultural and linguistic character of the states bordering Mexico are more nuanced than one might think.

Even so, with [41 million native speakers of Spanish and a further 11 million bilinguals](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2015/jun/29/us-second-biggest-spanish-speaking-country) in the US, the only country in the world with more is Mexico.

The statistics for the Hispanic demographic in the states bordering Mexico are as follows:

In both [California](http://www.pewhispanic.org/states/state/ca/) and [Texas](http://www.pewhispanic.org/states/state/tx/) 39% of the population is Hispanic, about a quarter of whom speak only English at home. In [Arizona](http://www.pewhispanic.org/states/state/az/), 31% are Hispanic, of which 34% are English only. The population of [New Mexico](http://www.pewhispanic.org/states/state/nm/) is 48% Hispanic, with 39% English only.  This comes out all told to around 29 million people, minus the English-only Hispanics still a healthy majority of Spanish speakers in the US. The lower percentage of English only in California and Texas testifies to both more recent immigration and heavy concentrations of Spanish speakers in particular areas, in Texas basically anywhere south of the Nueces River and in Far West Texas.

South [Florida](http://www.pewhispanic.org/states/state/fl/) is another example: although only 24% Hispanic in the whole state, 83% speak Spanish at home, likely a result of their concentration in only a few Florida counties. The large number of Puerto Ricans moving to Florida after the hurricane will likely change these statistics if they choose to remain.

What this vast number of Hispanophones in the US does not have, however, is a K-12 mono- or bilingual educational system, like, say, Francophone Canadians in Quebec. This alone prevents any serious heel-snapping: adults can get by in their daily lives, even vote, without ever uttering a word of English, but their children will be at least bilingual, and, unfortunately, uneducated in their first language.

This may be changing. In 2016 California voters approved [Proposition 58](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Proposition_58_(2016)), which removed previous restrictions on bilingual education, but it is still too early to tell what such a program would look like beyond assurances that families could choose either a traditional monolingual English program or a bilingual one.

So where would be the best place to live if you speak only Spanish? It depends on what lifestyle you prefer, neighborhoods in Los Angeles or San Diego, Spanish Harlem, or something more relaxed but still urban, in which case Beto's hometown has much to offer: [El Paso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Paso,_Texas). It's 80.7% Hispanic and has far more amenities than, say, [Laredo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laredo,_Texas) (95.6% Hispanic). But if your thing is fantastic avocados, canteloupe, and 10 lb. sacks of oranges for cheap, head for the Rio Grande Valley.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: If you've never eaten an avocado or canteloupe from the Valley, you can't possibly know what I'm talking about. I did, however, change the first sentence to eliminate any ambiguity.

Comment: Aren't those just Mexican [blood advocados](https://www.wsj.com/articles/bloody-struggle-erupts-over-avocado-trade-1391223373) too?

Comment: You are right about the phrase “snapping at the heels of English”. It’s not neutral at all. And that Russian is not a scholar either. He is a polyglot, according to the OP. I wish he would read your answer.

Comment: Excellent answer, though I think the original quote was misrepresented in the translation. The original line in Russian simply states that "Spanish is at English's heels." The snapping bit was suggested later by another user. It is also correct that the guy is no scholar, he's just a minor celebrity whose popularity among certain audiences is a mystery to many.

Comment: 10q for answer!

Comment: @undercat  and Enguroo: I'll just use his name then.

Comment: @undercat in the Russian line you are talking about there is an idiom which means to compete strongly with someone or something and have a chance of soon defeating or replacing them, so it’s very similar to “to snap at one’s heels”. It’s not correct to say that it should be interpreted as “to be at one’s heels”. That Russian polyglot really meant that Spanish might replace English, at least in some states (not just neighborhoods).

Comment: @Enguroo That's not what he said, rewind back to 8:45 and listen carefully. There is no claim English "might replace Spanish" which you are attributing to him. He simply states that multiple languages will likely remain even in the distant future. Furthermore, in his phrase that "even in the US, Spanish is at English's heels" there is no strong implication of violent competition, which "snapping at one's heals" implies. To me it sounds more like a poorly worded statement of the fact there are many native Spanish speakers in the US, which is why I think the use of that idiom is not justified.

Comment: @undercat good point. He is actually talking about diversity, not replacement. Но из песни слов не выкинешь. I agree he must have misused the idiom because it really doesn't fit in the context of the video. But does it make such a difference? The question of the OP concerned the states where one can live without speaking English. And I think the question has been fully answered. Let's just hope that YouTubers will choose their words more carefully.

Comment: @Enguroo Absolutely, and agreed. It was just a small nitpick with the wording.

Answer (score 9):

The question seems to be simple but there is no single right answer, I think. The national language of the USA is English (de facto). If you want to make your life there easy, you need to be able to speak, read, write in English, and understand what people around you say (not only in some areas but anywhere across the country). But even if you can do all of those things, it doesn't mean your life gets *easy*. What do we mean by *easy* after all?

Anyway, in 2009 I visited the USA (the state of New York) and stayed there for 4 months. I was happy to meet a lovely lady in her 50s, whose parents had immigrated from Puerto Rico when she was still a child. And she told me that her parents had never learnt English. They lived in a Spanish-speaking area, socializing with Spanish-speaking people only. Even though they lived in the US for decades, they never used English - they just couldn't and they were not that eager to learn. But I remember I could hear regret in that lady's voice...

I think there may be people able to answer this question better. But let's be realistic. No matter how *easy* it is for us to live in the US without speaking English, being able to speak English will make our life even *easier*.

Comment: Feel free to use or ignore https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_Spanish-speaking_population and https://wordsmeet.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/11-13_spanish_2012.jpg

Comment: If I remember well, there is no official language at the national level, in the USA. Many states made English official, but not all of them.

Comment: @spectras you are right. English is just the most commonly used, and it is the de facto national language of the United States.